# vsftp on centos

Tags: centos, ftp

I have trouble login to a centos box using root, password is correct, I suspect it's a file permission issue, how do I resolve this?

```
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
Command:    USER root
Response:   530 Permission denied.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete root from "/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers" and set "local_enable=YES".

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `root` from `/etc/ftpusers` if you really need to login to FTP using root account. It is extremely dangerous since FTP passwords are transferred in cleartext.